# How do you store a Java Boolean type variable in a PostgreSQL table with corresponding column data type defined as "bit"?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Now, the data type of the variable in my Java class is "boolean". I want to store it in a PostgreSQL table. The column in which I want to store my data has data type defined as "bit". But when I try to save the object which has this boolean variable, I get the error:

```
ERROR: column "isdeleted" is of type bit but expression is of type boolean
```

I'm using Hibernate to store the data. 
My code snippet for defining and mapping my variable:

```
@Column(name = "isDeleted")
private boolean isDeleted;
```

How do I save my object? Thank you!

Comment: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Exception-when-inserting-boolean-values-into-BIT-columns-td2168390.html

Answer (score 2):

Try using BOOLEAN data type, define your @Column annotation like that:

```
@Column(name = "isDeleted", columnDefinition = "boolean default true", nullable = false)
private boolean isDeleted = true;
```

Also, I think in NHibernate the column type is TrueFalse, which expects 'T' or 'F'.
You would need to change the column type to Boolean. Try this [link](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html)

Comment: Sorry, can't make changes to the specifications!

Answer (score 2):

Please use a proper `boolean` type in Postgres. Although it is possible to store boolean values in bit streams, it makes later usage complicated.

With the usual `boolean` you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE isdeleted;
```

Whereas with `bit` type you have to do bitwise operations:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE isdeleted > B'0'
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I know that and I want to, but this is the specification given to me. I can't make any changes to the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding PostgreSQL Dialect in your code 
"org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"

Answer (score 0):

Add below annotation above the field name, if using hibernate

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
@Column(name = "isDeleted")
private boolean isDeleted;
```